# MariaDB jdbc connection fails during bulk inserts

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I have a table in MariaDB with this spec:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages_txt` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `title` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `txt` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

and I want to insert about 2 million records into this table.
However, after inserting about 160K records the connection dies and I receive this exception:

```
at Main.main(Main.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Could not send query: Last packet not finished
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.executeQuery(MySQLProtocol.java:954)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:278)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Last packet not finished
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.packet.PacketOutputStream.startPacket(PacketOutputStream.java:38)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.packet.commands.StreamedQueryPacket.send(StreamedQueryPacket.java:76)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.executeQuery(MySQLProtocol.java:952)
    ... 22 more
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not send query: Last packet not finished
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:136)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MySQLStatement.java:262)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:285)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLStatement.java:313)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLPreparedStatement.java:156)
    at Main$1.process(Main.java:50)
```

but the MariaDB server is up and working! Is there any bugs in JDBC connector???
The version is 5.5.32-MariaDB.

Comment: Please file a bug in JIRA (https://mariadb.atlassian.net/), and include your data file. Also include parameters for the database  etc.

Comment: When this has happened with me, I was using mariaDB for my datasource using JBoss AS 7 Final. It was working perfectly till I decided to drop my database while JBoss is running, and then recreate the database. What I did to solve the problem was simply restarting JBoss.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Have you tried just using the MySQL Connector/J? MySQL and MariaDB are binary compatible, and I've never run into any issues there. The MySQL Connector has the benefit of a significantly larger community.

Comment: If you have licensing concerns, the MariaDB J Connector comes with the LGPL which is less restrictive than that of MySQL (GPL).

Comment: Your answer is not correct but by using MySQL connector, I found that the bug is in MariaDB's JDBC driver. Therefore, I accepted this :)